# Subroutine Workbook_Open not firing

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use the Workbook_Open routine in Excel to perform some checks upon open. It is located in the 'ThisWorkbook' section. From my investigations it seems to be related to a timing issue as if I rename the file to get the 'Enable Content' button the code always runs. If it is already a trrusted document it doesn't.

I have tried many troubleshooting steps, such as `stop`, `application.wait`, `msgbox`, switching off `screenupdating` and then switching it back on within another sub, and even tried removing the original two lines of code to a completely separate sub. I have also tried opening Excel first and then opening the document. Below is what I've currently got:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.OnTime Now, "Continue_Open"
End Sub

Sub Continue_Open()
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue ("00:00:01"))
    'Stop
    MsgBox "Workbook_Open called"
    'Check that VBA access is switched on
    'based on https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cristib/2012/02/29/vba-how-to-programmatically-enable-access-to-the-vba-object-model-using-macros/
    Call CheckIfVBAAccessIsOn

    'Add new Reference if required.
    Call AddReference
End Sub
```

Even if I only have `stop` in the routine it never runs if the document is trusted. That's why I feel it may be a timing issue, hence all the ways I have tried to troubleshoot it. All the attempted steps make no difference.

Comment: what do you have in your `CheckIfVBAAccessIsOn` and `AddReference` Subs ? because If I run this code when I comment these 2 lines, it runs just fine, and I'm getting a `MsgBox` with "Workbook_Open called"

Comment: Even if I reduce the code to the single line `MsgBox "Workbook_Open called"` it doesn't work if the document is trusted. FYI `CheckIfVBAAccessIsOn `is from the embedded URL and `AddReference` adds a reference to the project.

Comment: After a PC restart it seems as though the problem has disappeared. However it makes me wonder how reliable it is to use the `Workbook_Open` feature...

Comment: It depends what you have in it, I use it and it's working great. **BUT** I'm using it only for crucial items related to workbook event, everything else I have on a seperate module, I call it `MainInit` that fires when I need to run some Macro, not on `Open` event. Hope I've helped